# Fixed Header at top of scrolled list. Flex Layout with all columns same height

Tags: html, css

Can't seem to get this to work. Want to add a fixed header to the blue and green divs that doesn't scroll with the div. What makes this complicated is:

- Red Canvas on left is only element that shrinks in width
- Canvas element maintains width/height ratio, also shrinking in height
- As the Canvas shrinks in height, both the blue and green divs also shrink in height.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrx6zk27/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <canvas id="draw" width="250" height="300"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="center"><div id="center" class="scroll"></div></div>
  <div class="right"><div id="right" class="scroll"></div></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  max-width: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
}
.container > div {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 0;
}
.left {
  max-width: 250px;
  width: auto;
}
.left canvas {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.center {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: blue;
}
.right {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: green;
}
.scroll {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var c = document.getElementById("draw");
ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 250, 300);
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.font = "bold 40pt Arial";
ctx.fillText("CANVAS", 10, 100);

tmp = "";
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    tmp += "<p>" + i + "</p>";
}

document.getElementById("center").innerHTML = tmp;
document.getElementById("right").innerHTML = tmp;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Want to add a fixed header to the blue and green divs that doesn't scroll with the div

Check if the following works for you:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("draw");
ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 250, 300);
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.font = "bold 40pt Arial";
ctx.fillText("CANVAS", 10, 100);

tmp = "";
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  tmp += "<p>" + i + "</p>";
}

document.getElementById("center").innerHTML = tmp;
document.getElementById("right").innerHTML = tmp;
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
}
.container > div {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 0;
}
.left {
  max-width: 250px;
  width: auto;
  flex: 1;
}
.left canvas {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.center {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  background-color: #0000ff;
}
.right {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
.scroll {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 40px;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.header {
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.center .header {
  background-color: #aaaaff;
}
.right .header {
  background-color: #aaff00;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <canvas id="draw" width="250" height="300"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <div class="header">fixed header</div>
    <div id="center" class="scroll"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="header">fixed header</div>
    <div id="right" class="scroll"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good in FF & Chrome, but not IE, but that is my fault. My original fiddle and your update don't work in IE, but my real web site does. Must be something wrong on my side that I already figured out and just never put in the fiddle. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: Don't worry about it.  I edited my previous comment to indicate my original fiddle didn't work in IE either. Although maybe worth fixing the solution for others looking at this. Marking your fix as the solution. Thanks. Although can't award bounty for 24 hours. Didn't think it was a horribly difficult problem but couldn't figure it out and early neg's caused other people to not look at my question.

Comment: @Mike the problem was the missing `flex: 1` in the `.left` element. should be working on IE 11+ now.